# How to read and use data from DynamboDB in an Alexa skill

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I am building an Alexa skill that retrieves some data from a DynamoDB table and then needs to use it in another function or as speech output. My idea was to use async/await but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});


var params = {
 TableName: 'someTableName',
 Key: {'UserID': '1'}
};

var getDataPromise = docClient.get(params).promise();

getDataPromise.then(
  function(data) {
    console.log(data.Item);  // I need to return data.Item to somehow use in .speechoutput()
  }
).catch(
  function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

If I create an `async` function, I'm not sure where I would put `await` or how I would return the data to `.speechoutput()`. I have tried putting `await` in front of the `docClient` function, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

async function getData() {
  var params = {
   TableName: 'someTableName',
   Key: {'UserID': '1'}
  };

  var getDataPromise = await docClient.get(params).promise();

  getDataPromise.then(
    function(data) {
      console.log(data.Item);  // I need to return data.Item to somehow use in .speechoutput()
    }
  ).catch(
    function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}

getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might not be getting async/await.

Await makes JS wait until a promise is resolved and gets whatever is returned on resolution.

`getDataPromise` contains the result of the `docClient.getParams()` operation once it resolves, which should be the data object.

AFAICT, your code fails because you are trying to "then" a plain old data object.